# how can two methods in same class can access it members in python

Tags: python

```
class boy:
  """Details"""

  def __init___(self):
    print("Details")

  def name(self,x,y,z):
    a=x.title() + ' '
    b=y.title() + ' '
    c=z.title()
    nam = a + b + c
    print(nam)

  def age(self,nu):
    f = int(num)
    if f>18:
     return 1
    else:
     print("\nSorry you must be at least 18 years to continue")
     return -1

  def p_details(self,cc):     #need to print all detals by calling this method.
    print("Name :" + self.nam )
    print("Age :" + self.f)
    print("Country :"+ con)

a = raw_input("Enter the first name :")
b = raw_input("Enter the middle name :")
c = raw_input("Enter the last name :")
num = raw_input("Enter the age :")
inp=boy()

if(inp.age(num) == 1 ):
   con = raw_input("\nPlease enter your country :")
   inp.p_details(con)
```

As i am new into pyhton the question may seem silly or foolish but i really appreciate a help. What i need is to call p_details and print all the details.

Comment: you forgot to pass your parameters. the `boy()` should have a,b,c as parameters, then set `self.age = a`, etc. You're mixing up variables with members. Check python object syntax.

Comment: What you have written so far has problems on so many level (sorry, really). Please read a good book on Python and come back when you have something specific. As it stands this is too broad, in my opinion.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan i will do ..as a starter there will be mistakes, a lot of mistakes. what i need was a help as i was unable to understand the working for function and class,..anyway i ill sort it out thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class boy():
    def __init___(self, num):
        self.age = int(num)

num = raw_input("Enter the age :")

inp = boy(num)

if inp.age < 18:
    ....
```

Your class should work like this.  The way you wrote it, `inp` has no age attribute to evaluate.  But as pointed out in the comments, there's really a lot wrong with your code there.  The way you're using methods suggests you aren't clear on how classes and methods work, exactly.  Also, getting user input opens up a whole host of issues - like what happens if the user doesn't enter a numeral when asked, and instead types, say, "old enough"?

Answer (score 0):

Add class members into your `__init__`, like this:

```
def __init___(self,x, y, z):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
    print("Details")
```